# How to start .NET 6 console app in WSL2 Ubuntu distro from VS2022?

Tags: .net-6.0, wsl-2

[EDIT] I am using Ubuntu 22.04. Using Ubuntu 20.04 I was able to install .NET 6 and run the console app.

I am struggling for several days with an odd issue. I have VS2022 Professional running on Windows 11 with enabled WSL. I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 from Microsoft store. However when I try to debug a console app in the Ubuntu's distro it is not possible since it says that I don't have .NET 6 SDK installed on the distro which is not correct:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uP72x.png)

Here is my launchSettings.json:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "ConsoleApp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "remoteDebugEnabled": false
    },
    "WSL : Ubuntu 22.04": {
      "commandName": "WSL",
      "distributionName": "Ubuntu-22.04"
    }
  }
}
```

I have installed VsDbg as well:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAMfH.png)

Any advice how to deal with this?

I have tried to clean the project and to rebuild. I have followed the "install" button in Visual Studio and the installation of the .NET 6 SDK passes successfully and yet I have the same problem. I did several restarts of VS and of PC as well.